# Create multiple empty directories from user input, and collect names of directories to create

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Okay, all I know I can do this but I'm having a hard time remembering how or finding the right example.  Here is what I am trying to do:

Ask the user for how many directories to create.

```
set /p Path="Where do you want these directories created? "
set /p DirCount="How many directories do you need to create? "
set count=%DirCount%
```

Ask user for first through * directory name and create empty directory.

```
for /f "count=%count%-1" do (
    set /p DirName="Enter name of %count% empty directory: " &&
    md %Path%\%DirName%
 )
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Okay, I've got it working sort of: `set /p Path="C:\Test "
set "DirCount=1"
set /p DirCount="How many directories do you need to create? (Default: %count%): "
for /L %%N in (1,1,%count%) do (set /p %DIR%%%N="Enter %%N directory name: " & md "C:\Test\%DIR%%%N")
set "DirCount=" `

Comment: The syntax of the [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) is completely wrong; type `for /?` into a command prompt window and read the appearing help text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%dircount%) DO (
 SET /p dirname="directory %%a name :"
 CALL MD "%destdir%\%%dirname%%"
)
```

would be one way - I used a fixed directoryname `destdir`

Note that `path` is used by the system to find executables so that any directory in the predefined `path` variable can contain a required executable. It should not be varied by users.

Comment: Magoo - I'd like your answer a 100 times if I could.  Thank you for setting me up for success.